# Want to know automation in verifone terminal is possible or not?

Tags: automation, point-of-sale, verifone

I want know about test automation in VeriFone terminals--is possible or not? Is there anyway to do automation for it?

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about test automation.  I've updated your question to make that more clear.  Please revert if my assumption is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called VeriFind that is packaged with the DTK that is supposed to be for this purpose (note: I've never used it).

From the documentation:

> The VeriFind Test Automation Tool is an integrated testing tool that
>   aids testing applications written for Verix eVo terminals. This
>   Windows-based tool simulates user actions, such as key presses and
>   magnetic card swipes, which help automate the execution of test
>   suites. It provides a scripting utility, file transfer utility,
>   screens on the terminal, RAM status, date and time as in the terminal,
>   and records user actions to play back later.